# rails Glyphicon are not displayed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

gemfile :

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'sass'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    gem 'rails_admin'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'gmaps4rails', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
    gem 'geocoder'
    gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.7.1', require: 'google/api_client'
    gem 'underscore-rails', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.3'
    gem 'markerclustererplus-rails'
    gem "font-awesome-rails"
    gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
    gem 'jquery-rails' gem 'jquery-turbolinks'gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
    gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
     gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
    group :development, :test do  gem 'byebug'
    end
    group :development do
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
      gem 'spring'
    end
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.validate
//= require validation
//= require jquery-1.5.min
//= require jcarousel
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require google_maps
//= require markerclusterer
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

custom.css.scss:

```
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
```

help me, please
[image]Icons are not displayed at all
Sometimes displays a black square
Can this situation be due to the use of a script?
Use Carousel and used Google Map API

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star</button> <br>
```

Comment: can you add an screenshot to see where it is not being displayed.?

Comment: You may need to show us your output HTML/CSS.  Also did you want to render your icons using Font Awesome or Glyph Icons?  Bootstrap is prepackaged with the latter, but you seem to be importing the former as well...

Comment: @Robert C 
I do not care what add icons
if it does not add them, and then we can use Awesome

Answer (score -3):

add this to your custom.css.scss

> @import "font-awesome";

Comment: Font Awesome and Glyphicons are different icon sets that utilize different class names ( `.fa` vs `.glyphicon` ).

Comment: @StivenFrams this is scss, and proper syntax. Are you sure your editor supports SCSS?

Comment: @ABDULSAMIIAJALA please provide some information about WHY this is the answer, so people might learn something instead of just having their problem fixed.